# Creating a map property and enumerating its properties in a template?

Tags: ember.js, dictionary, enumeration

I have poured through a ton of documentation and I can't seem to find an answer to a very basic question. I have a component that needs to store a map (key/value) as a property:

```
App.SimpleTestComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    data: Ember.A(),
    actions: {
        add: function() {
            this.get('data').set('test', 'value');
        }
    }
});
```

The template for the component looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/simple-test">
    {{#each item in data}}
        <p>
            <strong>{{item.key}}:</strong>
            {{ item.value}}
        </p>
    {{/each}}
    <button {{action 'add'}}>Add</button>
</script>
```

However, this doesn't work. [No items are displayed after clicking the button](http://jsbin.com/coruyirizu/1/edit?html,js,output) and the problem seems to be with the `{{#each}}` block. How do I correctly enumerate over the `data` property?

Answer (score 3):

1. `Ember.A()` is shorthand for Ember.NativeArray. This is why your
   code isn't working, you're also calling `.set` which is a method
   inherited from `Ember.Observable`. So what you're really doing is
   just setting an object property on the array rather than its
   content.
2. What you probably want is `Ember.Map` which is an internal class
   but many developers use it anyways.   You will still need to return an
   array of objects as the following example:

   ```
    App.SimpleTestComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
       // Shared map among all SimpleTestComponents
       map: Ember.Map.create(),
       // Or per component map
       init: function() {
         this.set('map', Ember.Map.create());
       },

       data: function() {
         // this doesn't have to be locally scoped...
         var arr = Ember.A();
         this.get('map').forEach(function(key, value) {
           arr.addObject({key: key, value: value});
         });
         return arr;
       }.property('map'),

       actions: {
           add: function() {
               this.get('map').set('test', 'value');
           }
       } 
   });
   ```

   This doesn't really work when you have keys that have multiples
   values simply becauses `Ember.Map` always overwrites on `.set`
3. If performance is of concern and you would like to have multiple 
   values per key then you will need to implement your own 
   map class with and a handlebars helper to display it.